# Как заставить приложение "Галерея" Android обновиться?

Tags: java, android, файлы, android-intent

Всем, Привет! Сейчас работаю над одним приложением под Android для манипуляций с файлами. Столкнулся с одной непоняткой... Допустим у вас есть где-то на диске какой нибудь файл фотографии. Он у вас будет отображаться в приложении **галерея** в виде предпросмотра. И вот вы захотели его удалить с помощью свой программы использовав что то типа этого:

```
existingFile.delete();
```

И вот логично было бы предположить что после такой операции он должен оттуда исчезнуть. В моём случае он из галереи не исчезает, но при нажатии открыть выскакивает ошибка. (Т.е. файла фактически физические уже нет а в галереи он еще светится). Проблема исчезает при перезагрузке устройства. Но может есть ещё другое решение? Может нужно использовать какой нибудь широковещательный интент?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все правильно, Gallery это БД, которую надо обновлять после манипуляций с изображениями. Делается это так:

```
existingFile.delete();

context.sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(existingFile)));
```

Этот бродкаст ловится приложением галереи и он сам обновит информацию о файле

Comment: Спасибо всё работает!